# Devexpress gridview: Set SelectedRowsCount to 0

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am using a DevExpress gridview which should start with `SelectedRowsCount == 0`.
But the gridview always takes the first row.
Is it possible to set the selection to 0 at the beginning? 
I just want to get a value when a row is clicked.

Comment: best would be to log a support ticket at devexpress.com
Have a look here:
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q328329/aspxgridview-how-to-clear-selection

This link might help with your requirement

Comment: Need to see your code, sounds like you're missing something. Also WPF, ASP.NET, etc?

Comment: thanks, i solved the problem

Comment: @AndreasSolsbacher then you should add the answer below to help people in future.